# CXF failing after upgrading Jackson lib

Tags: json, cxf, jackson

I have just upgraded from Jackson 2.1.1 to 2.2.2 and it has caused the 
following exception:

javax.ws.rs.client.ClientException: .No message body writer has been 
found for class : class uk.co.tbp.gabble.domain.User, ContentType : 
application/json.

Has something changed in the way I need to configure the provider?

Nic

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to CXF 2.7.6-SNAPSHOT fixes the issue